# drupal 7 converting datetime to string

Tags: php, datetime, drupal, drupal-7

I was wondering if anybody has had a similar issue in drupal

Recoverable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string in DatabaseStatementBase->execute() (line 2171 of /path-to-drupal-folder/includes/database/database.inc).

This occurs when I am trying to submit a form that does not have any DateTime objects

https://www.drupal.org/node/1851478
following that link, do I have to uninstall the Date/Time module? If that is a solution, is there another?

Comment: have you checked the column datatype in your database table. And then what data you are inserting into the column.

Comment: @ViswanathPolaki. Yes I have fixed it. When I set the column datatype to datetime, I thought that I was supposed to insert it as a date object.  It works now when I insert it as a string